# Randomize Name Button Only Works Once

Tags: swift

I'm building a random name-generator app in Swift for fun.

To do this I created two arrays; one with a list of potential first names, one with a list of potential last names.

```
// Array example:

let firstName: [String] = ["first", "name", "etc",]

let lastName: [Sting] = ["last","name", "etc"]


// Then implemented a randomizing mechanism with arc4random_uniform then 

lazy var randomFirst = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstName.count)))

lazy var randomLast = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lastName.count)))


// I then have a button which updated a textfield with the new names:

@IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func getName(_ sender: Any) { 
      NameLabel.text = firstName[randomFirst] + lastName[randomLast]    
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that the button only works once. onClick, it updates to a new random name, but will not do so with any subsequent taps.
As far as I can tell, the button only calls for the .count once and does not/will not/cannot do so upon additional button taps?

I'm trying to make it so that it will generate a new name upon each button tap.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate the random index for your names every time the button event fires. Like the following:

```
@IBAction func getName(_ sender: Any) {

      // GENERATE INDEXES
      var randomFirst = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstName.count)))
      var randomLast = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lastName.count)))

      // SET NAME LABEL
      NameLabel.text = firstName[randomFirst] + lastName[randomLast]    
}
```

The reason for this is the `lazy` operator. As you have it currently set up the variable instantiated with the `lazy` operator will initialize itself with a random number the first time it is called. Every time its referenced after that it will load up its last loaded value.

Answer (score 0):

The `lazy` means, that the value of the variable is calculated only once and then it's used like a constant. You must use computed variables instead:

```
var randomFirst { 
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(firstName.count)))
}

var randomLast {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lastName.count)))
}
```

Comment: The purpose for the lazy operator is, without it I end up with the following runtime error:

"Cannot use instance member 'firstName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Comment: @RonnWeasley, just use my snippet while you don't understand what are you doing.